# Having trouble downloading pictures from a RSS feed?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm having trouble coming up with the correct code to download pictures from a RSS feed and then handing that download off to RadControls slide View or Pagination.

The only thing I can get with the code I'm using is either the text for the pictures or just thumbnails of the pictures, not the full image. I must be missing something or leaving something out.

This is for Windows Phone C#

The web links for the RSS feeds are generic for testing purposes.

```
//Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void FlickrSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler         

    (webclient_DownloadStringCompleted);             
}

void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
    // parsing Flickr 

    XElement XmlTweet = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
    XNamespace ns = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tag="; // flilckr
    listBox1.ItemsSource = 
        from tweet in XmlTweet.Descendants("item")
        select new FlickrData
        {
            ImageSource = tweet.Element(ns + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
            Message = tweet.Element("description").Value,
            UserName = tweet.Element("title").Value,
            PubDate = DateTime.Parse(tweet.Element("pubDate").Value)
        };
}
```

Comment: Provide the complete image url you are using in the WebClient.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem i'm having. This is all I have. This is code that I am trying to use from a provided example project.

Comment: from what I understand I need to download the photos to Isolated phone storage and then hand them off to the controls or photo viewer. Is that correct?

Sorry for maybe asking for a lot of info. I'm studying this stuff in school and trying to write code at the same time, so I need help filling in some gaps here and there. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: here is the Flickr link I'm trying to stream
http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157633154413349&nsid=93853091@N07&lang=en-us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way you are parsing & fetching the inner data is erroneous. I have closely verified the XML data from Flickr and modified the logic accordingly.

Here goes the complete code:

```
void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
    // parsing Flickr 

    XElement XmlTweet = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
    string ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

    XName entry = XName.Get("entry", ns);
    XName loc = XName.Get("loc", ns);
    XName title = XName.Get("title", ns);
    XName published = XName.Get("published", ns);
    XName link = XName.Get("link", ns);
    XName content = XName.Get("content", ns);
    XName url = XName.Get("url", ns);

    listBox1.ItemsSource = 
        from tweet in XmlTweet.Elements(entry)
        select new FlickrData
        {
            ImageSource = tweet.Element(link).Attribute("href").Value,
            Message = tweet.Element(content).Value,
            UserName = tweet.Element(title).Value,
            PubDate = DateTime.Parse(tweet.Element(published).Value)
        };
}
```